# Global Picklist Metadata in Mavensmate

Tags: deployment, mavensmate, global-picklist

I am trying to deploy global picklist metadata through Mavensmate but I cannot find the global picklist metadata type inside my mavensmate subscription index. Are global picklist metadata supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are supported. It sometimes happens that they are not selectable however. If you have MavensMate version 6.0, to solve this, open your project, click MavensMate -> Metadata -> Update Project Metadata Index (.org_metadata). When this is done, edit your project using MavensMate -> Project -> Edit project, you should be able to select the Global Picklists in the Metadata Subscription List on the advanced tab.

EDIT: make sure MavensMate is set up to use API version 37.0

Comment: So I followed the steps you mentioned but I still only see the following options in my subscription index: http://screencast.com/t/XIYqVVS5 I must note I have Mavensmate prerelease version 7 installed. This is necessary for me to access sandbox with 1.1 TLS after salesforce disabled 1.0 TLS.

Comment: Can you check your MavensMate setting for global, project and user, and make sure they are all set up to use API version 37.0?

Comment: It is set to 34.0 - is it OK to update to 37.0?  http://screencast.com/t/y8qyOEclT

Comment: I think that will solve the problem, yes.

Comment: THANK YOU. I updated to 37.0, saved setting by clicking anywhere on mavensmate, quit both sublime and mavensmate, re-opened both apps, and  then was able to follow your above instructions.

Comment: I am using API & and tried with 40 too... I can get GlobalPicklists, but not field specific picklists for standard objects (Account, etc). any suggestions?

Comment: For that you have to use StandardValueSet. Check this page to see a list of all names that you need to use for the standard fields: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/standardvalueset_names.htm